# Can I run python scripts in colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am trying to get some open source software working. It uses things that I don't have on my system (pytorch for example) and so I thought that I could try to run it on Google Colab.

When I tried to do it though, there are some python scripts that I have to run after cloning a directory from a github repository. I guess I can't run another python script from inside a Jupyter Notebook, and so I suppose that I'm trying to do something with Colab that it isn't designed to do?

Is there something available that is more like a terminal, but using the software, GPUs etc. that are available on Colab?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run any shell command from jupyter-like environment (which includes `colab`) using `!` in code cell, for example

```
!ls
```

Would list all files in colab's `cwd`.
To run `python` script you could do:

```
!python script.py
```

It works just like terminal (it might be `python3`, not sure how it's setup un `colab`)

Answer (score 3):

You can call your script too.

```
!python script.py
```

But you need to put the script there, probably by `git clone` or direct uploading.

Comment: You'll get a richer notebook experience using the `%run` magic command for running a python script, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42203142/8508004).  As for getting the file, you can directly `curl` or use `wget` to bring in the script if it is public, too, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48587645/8508004).

Answer (score 1):

As [Wayne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8508004/wayne) mentions in the comment [korakot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59628698/1785661), you can use the magic command

```py
%run 'script.py'
```

This also allows you to do e.g. run in the notebook's namespace by using the `-i` parameter

```py
%run -i 'script.py'
```