# View Jupyter notebooks hosted on Sharepoint

Tags: python, sharepoint, jupyter-notebook, onedrive, viewer

In our institute, we use OneDrive / Sharepoint from Microsoft to share files with each other. I am also sharing my Jupyter notebooks - with extension *.ipynb - there. Unfortunately, when one clicks on such a file the message "Hmm... looks like this file doesn't have a preview we can show you" appears. In my case I developed my notebooks with python. It's not necessary that my colleagues can run the notebook, but it would indeed be much easier to be able to install a kind of plugin for previewing on the Sharepoint server. Is there any product that can work like this? Otherwise I'll have to always export the file to HTML or so :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't any good news so far. Such a plugin seems to be unavailable as yet. For the meantime, I have automated the exporting of the notebooks to HTML on my Windows 10 machine as follows:

```
For /R .\ %G IN (*.ipynb) do jupyter nbconvert --to html "%G"
```

For use in a *.bat file, you'll have to double the %-signs.

Comment: Do you embed it in a sharepoint site using the HTML or do you have to proceed as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31855794/how-can-i-share-jupyter-notebooks-with-non-programmers

Comment: No, please! I just saved my notebooks to a folder on my OneDrive. When I choose "view online", my browser opens and shows the notebooks in a Sharepoint environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a python file that automates the process of creating HTMLs out of Jupyter notebooks.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).